# Jquery / javascript text animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I have seen several sites with some text animations, and have been unable to locate anyway of accomplishing this on my site.. if you go here 
https://www.battlefield.com/

the text is animated however not sure what the text is using. how can I animate text simple fade transition like on the above site.

example

line 1 hello
line 2 welcome
line 3 to our community

etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they did, is strange, and I have no idea why they did it that way.

Have a look at that URL:

https://media-www-battlefieldwebcore.spark.ea.com/content/dam/ea/battlefield-portal/sequence/BF1_Animated_Logo_94.png

This is only one of ~110 full sized images (just change the sequence number in the filename) they load into the page and then ... playback *manually*. That means, they update the image source ~15-20 times per second via javascript. That explains the flickering image at the beginning, when the images are being loaded for the first time... Maybe they even liked that effect.

So it is not an animated PNG, it is no multimedia content, it is just about 100 frames that manually get assigned to the image.

You may want to inspect the page, search for an element with the tag `<bf-animated-sequence>`. It contains some sub elements, one of them is the image that gets its src changed several times a second.

And - *please* - don't follow their example, for the sake of your viewers. There are much better ways to do that (canvas, video playback, whatever).

For the text-animation, I recommend reading the jquery animate api: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

[edit]
With jquery you can do something like this:

```js
    $(function(){

        var $texts = $("#textfield .text");
        
        var textIndex = 0;

        function nextLine(){

        //Step 1: Fade in text
        $($texts[textIndex]).animate({opacity:1,"margin-top":12}, 500, "linear", function(){
        
            //Step 2: Fade out text
            setTimeout(function(){        
                $($texts[textIndex]).animate({opacity:0,"margin-top":20}, 500, "linear", function(){
                    //Step 3: Reset current and call next text
                    $($texts[textIndex]).css({"margin-top":20});
                    textIndex++;
                    textIndex %= $texts.length;
                    nextLine();
                    
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
        
        }
        
        nextLine();
        


    });
```

```css
    #textfield{
        border:1px solid black;
        height:40px;
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        right:10px;
        top:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #textfield .text{
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:20px;
        font-family:Arial;
        opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="textfield">
         <div class="text">Hello</div>
         <div class="text">Welcome to</div>
         <div class="text">our site</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Woah that is weird, and from a major game publisher too.

Comment: I guess they did not create their website on their own but hired a low-cost, mid-qualified agency employing cheap staff to maximize their own profit... that's the result. However, nearly nobody buys the game because of the website. And we know how much value you have to EA as soon as you have bought the game.

Comment: cannot seem to get this to go up instead of down

Comment: I made some major changes to the javascript as well as a slight change in the css: In the js, I removed the calls of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. In the css `display:none` is not longer used but `opacity:0`, Also, the `margin-top` values have been adapted.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with the settings but I believe this could point you closer in the right direction.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations

Comment: I am not talking about the battlefield effect the text above it

Comment: Are you talking about the breathtaking, exhilarating?

Comment: yep I want to have different messages just like that

Comment: Please visit this link and let me know if this is what you are wanting? https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations/

Comment: Download the project files from that link and it will give you the code for all of the demos.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a [CSS3 keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) animation (I'd strongly suggest you to consider going this route, it will be ***much*** lighter resource consumption-wise):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: boder-box;
}

.animateText div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: blurFadeInOut 2s ease-in backwards;
}

.animateText div.line-1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animateText div.line-2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animateText div.line-3 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 30px;
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animateText">
  <div class="line-1">Hello</div>
  <div class="line-2">Welcome</div>
  <div class="line-3">To our community</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is that it is not very scalable. What if you want to add another line? And another one? Maybe even generated in a newsticker-manner? For the example above, it works perfectly (therefor the upvote), but it is not really generalizable without a lot of effort